# How to deploy multiple Lambda's in CFN Template through Codepipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

**Usecase**

I have a cloudformation Stack with more then 15 Lambdas in it. I can able to deploy the stack through `Codepipeline` which consists of two stages `CodeCommit` and `CodeDeploy`. In this approach all my lambda code is in cloudformation template(i.e.inline code). For Security concerns i want to change this `Inline` to `S3` which inturn requires `S3BucketName` and `S3Key`.

**As a temporary workaround**

As of now i am zipping each lambda file and passing manually `S3keyName` and `bucketname` as a parameters to my stack .

> *Is there any way possible to do this step via Codepipeline ?*

**My Assumption on CodeBuild**

I Know we can use the `CodeBuild` for it. But upto now i have seen `CodeBuild` is only used to build `package.json` file. But in my usecase i dont have any . And also i can see it is possible to specify `cloudformation package` command to wrap my lambda from local to S3 this command will generate S3 codeuri`, but this is for Serverless Applications where there will be single lambda but in my case i have 15.

**What i had tried**

I know that as soon as you give a `git push` to `codecommit` it will keep you code in S3. So what i thought is to get the `S3BucketName` and `S3KeyName` from the codecommit pushed file and pass these parameters to my CFN template. I can able to get the `S3BucketName` but `S3KeyName` i dont know how to get that ? And i dont know whether this tried apporach is a workable one ?

BTW i know i can use shell script just to automate this process. But is there a way possible to do it via **CODE PIPELINE** ?

**Update--Tried Serverless Approach**

Basically i run two build actions with two different runtimes(i.e.Nodejs,Python) which runs independently. So when i use serverless approach each build will create a template-export.yml file with codeuri of bucketlocation , that means i will have `two template-export.yml files` . One problem with `Serverless` approach it must have to `create changeset` and then it trigger `Execute changeset`. Because of that i need to `merge those two template-export.yml files` and run this `create changeset` action followed by `execute changeset`. But i didn't know is there a command to merge two `SAM templates`.Otherwise one template-export.yml stack will replace other template-export.yml stack.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right, you just need an S3 Bucket and Key to be piped into your Lambda CF template. To do this I'm using the `ParameterOverrides` declaration in my pipeline.

Essentially, the pipeline is a separate stack and picks up a CF template located in the root of my source. It then overrides two parameters in that template that point it to the appropriate S3 bucket/key.

```
        - Name: LambdaDeploy
          Actions:
          - Name: CreateUpdateLambda
          ActionTypeId:
            Category: Deploy
            Owner: AWS
            Provider: CloudFormation
            Version: 1
          Configuration:
            ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE
            Capabilities: CAPABILITY_IAM
            RoleArn: !GetAtt CloudFormationRole.Arn
            StackName: !Join
              - ''
              - - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${CoreStack}ProjectName'
                - !Sub '${ModuleName}-app'
            TemplatePath: SourceOut::cfn-lambda.yml
            ParameterOverrides: '{ "DeploymentBucketName" : { "Fn::GetArtifactAtt" : ["BuildOut", "BucketName"]}, "DeploymentPackageKey": {"Fn::GetArtifactAtt": ["BuildOut", "ObjectKey"]}}'
```

Now, the fact that you have fifteen Lambda functions in this might throw a wrench in it. For that I do not exactly have an answer since I'm actually trying to do the exact same thing and package up multiple Lambdas in this kind of way.

Comment: Great @Guestie. I am digging for the same approach. Unfortunately this wont help me. Because, each of my lambda require external dependencies and they need to be kept in the same bucket but with different objectkey. I can see the codebuild has option for multiple output artifacts instead i copied my lambda functions to s3 through build commands (i.e.`aws s3 cp ..`). Thanks for your time.

Comment: BTW you need to include `InputArtifacts' key in `Deploy` stage with values `SourceOut` & `Buildout` since you are using these in `Deploy` stage. Then only your deploy stack will run.

Answer (score 0):

There's documentation on deploying multiple Lambda functions via CodePipeline and CloudFormation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/build-pipeline.html

I believe this will still upload the function code to S3, but it will leverage AWS tooling to make this process simpler.

Comment: Thanks @TimB for your time. Please check my `Update` section of my question.